# unregister BroadcastReceiver after app kill/crash

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I register my custom `BroadcastReceiver` with `registerReceiver()` in `onStart()` and `unregisterReceiver()` in `onStop()`.

Everything works fine, until someone kills the app during runtime. A new app start registered the `BroadcastReceiver` a second (or more) time.

How can I be sure, that only one instance is registered?

Comment: hmmm save the "registered" state in shared preferences, set it to false after you unregister and to true after register, check before registering and try to unregister if is true)... but still i don't getting why you need this... if this broadcast reciver is setted from the code where is the problem? if whole app is killed (and it was registered from code not from manifest) AFAIK it should no longer respond on the intent ...

Comment: Are you sure? What if the app restarts? Is the "old" registered receiver also killed?

Comment: yes, i'm sure ... do a simple test with [such activity](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/6616c027b18d413b48a1) ... start the app,  now from command broadcast `adb shell am broadcast -a "pl.selvin.android.broadcastkilled"` ... then kill app like `adb shell am force-stop "pl.selvin.android.broadcastkilled"` ... then broadcast again ... check the logcat's  logs