# Handle programmatically unregister BroadcastReceiver on process death

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-broadcastreceiver, kill-process

In my app I register `BroadcastReceiver` programmatically like that and unregister it in appropriate time with respect to my app's business logic.

```
 receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {...}
```

I want to make sure that when my app's process unexpectedly die (get killed) no memory leak is caused by the receiver and if it does what are my options?

(Already check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), [this great article](http://codetheory.in/android-broadcast-receivers/) and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045342/unregister-broadcastreceiver-after-app-kill-crash) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make sure that when my app's process unexpectedly die (get killed) no memory leak is caused by the receiver and if it does what are my options?

When an app process gets killed by the system (quite) everything associated with the process is "gone". No memory leaks from the app component's (`Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`) side can be expected.

**Edit**
When process get killed `ActivityManagerService` clean all app resources using `cleanUpApplicationRecordLocked` method [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#15504).
You can clearly see that all resources including all registered broadcast receivers being cleaned.([Ln. 15598](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#15598))