# Background data collector in Android restarts when App is terminated

Tags: android, android-service, accelerometer, android-lifecycle

I want to collect accelerometer data with my app. Therefore I created a service, so the app collects the data in the background, even when the app is no longer open.

Problem is, that when I close the app, the service gets terminated as well and restarts. During that time it won't collect data.

I tried both `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` and `START_STICKY`, both with the same result: when the app closes, the service restarts.

Is there way to prevent the service completely from stopping when the app is terminated?

> Note that my service is running in a separate process.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // start thread
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("SensorData", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    looper = thread.getLooper();
    handler = new BGHndlr(looper);

    sensorMngr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    reader = new SensorReader(sensorMngr);
    accSensor = reader.getSingleSensorOfType(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
    message.arg1 = startId;
    handler.sendMessage(message);

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

Nested class:

```
public class BGHndlr extends Handler implements SensorEventListener {

    public BGHndlr(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        oSensorManager.registerListener(this, oAcceleroMeter, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    //int i = 0;
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> both with the same result: when the app closes, the service restarts.

This is a [normal `Android` behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261258/handle-programmatically-unregister-broadcastreceiver-on-process-death/40261311#40261311), there is nothing an `Android` application developer can do about it.

> Note that my service is running in a separate process.

Same as before (*all in your question proves it*)... That said, the answer to

> Is there way to prevent the service completely from stopping when the app is terminated?

is No. You, as others, should stick to the `Android` components' lifecycle.

Comment: WhatsApp & Co did it, so there's gotta be a way.

Comment: @keinabel Let me do some testing to refresh memory... Also tell me how exactly do you _"terminate"_ the app?

Comment: @keinabel No changes by now. Tested (`Android` 4.2) and it's valid: removing (swiping out) the app from recent apps restarts the service with the `android:process` tag... _"WhatsApp & Co did it"_: how do you know a service wasn't recreated? what if the service had a bound client(s)? how did you "terminate" the "WhatsApp & Co" app(s)?