# Background Service Stop when removing app from recent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, background-service, oppo

Background service is stop, when removing my app from recent in oppo & vivo mobiles, & Broadcast reciever also not working in that case.

Comment: Very nice to know. Thank you.

Comment: Bad day, isn't it ?

Comment: i don't understand why companies change the functionality of basic codes

Comment: Mostly because they want their phones to excel in battery consumption, users will judge their company for battery consumption and not how well an app runs on it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40261311/3290339

Comment: please post your manifest

Comment: thanks for your response but, now issue is resolved. :)

Comment: How have to resolved issue. I am facing same problem in broadcast receiver

Comment: allow app to auto start & put a alarm manager that hit every minute & triger a broadcast reciever programatically

Comment: @YogeshPaliyal Is your solution work on latest Android versions too? Isn't Alarm Manager having issues in latest Android versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same issue with Oppo, Vivo, Mi and etc phones,

1. after removing from recent applications app was getting killed even services was getting killed

Solution: I had add autostart permissions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47307864/7579041) in my application and it worked.

2. After resolving this issue my app was getting frozen/killed after sometime running in background due to DOZE mode
   Solution: for this condition [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49098293/7579041) worked and now my app is working in background in any device
3. After above things do this:

intent.setClassName("com.coloros.oppoguardelf",                                 "com.coloros.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerConsumptionActivity");
startActivity(intent);

call above intent, it will redirect you to battery option, "Disable Background Freeze, Abnormal Apps Optimization and Doze from \"Energy Saver ->youAPP"

Note: Once you call above intent, there you may get different options to turn off Battery saving options.

Comment: it is not working for me in Vivo devices. can you please help me?

Comment: Sure, Please mention the device which you are using, then I can help further

Comment: Please update your error message, or ping me in chat

Comment: Have tried it but dind't work on oppo. Any other solution?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing

Comment: Sadly is that this might be working on some devices but still not working on OPPO devices, I've tested on OPPO A1601 running Android 6.0(ColorOS 3.0). Even though I have whitelisted the app in "AutoStart" and "PowerSaving", when I call `isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations()`, it still always return a false, and If I remove the app from the recent list it still gets killed. The weirdest thing is that the page `Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS` doesn't exist! It seems like OPPO is not following standard about "DOZE mode" and they just kill anything from recent Apps brutally.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You have to return START_STICKY;

Please refer this link :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm

example :

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Nullable

@Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
  return null;
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 

{

  // Let it continue running until it is stopped.

Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return START_STICKY;

   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {

 super.onDestroy();

Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
}
```

Comment: the devices mentioned in question behaves differently, for this START_STICKY doesnt work, solution I have mentioned as a answer

Answer (score 1):

yes.
if you want the service to start over you need to configure it as 'sticky':

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

After doing this, follow the accepted answer, it will work.

Comment: the devices mentioned in question behaves differently, for this START_STICKY doesnt work, solution I have mentioned as a answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask your users to whitelist your app in their settings for it to work in these phones. The custom OS on these phones only allows whitelisted apps like whatsapp,fb etc to work in background, other apps have to whitelisted manually from settings

Comment: even broadcast receivers?